# Generating mp4 video from list of image takes a time

Tags: java

The code bellow are for generated video based on list on images. The purposes are to create timelapse-video based on image on selected folder. Thus, here are the class that responsible to make a video

```
public class AviCreator implements ControllerListener, DataSinkListener
{
    private boolean doIt(
        int width,
        int height,
        int frameRate,
        MediaLocator outML)
    {
        ImageDataSource ids = new ImageDataSource(width, height, frameRate);

        Processor p;

        try
        {
            System.err.println(
                "- create processor for the image datasource ...");
            p = Manager.createProcessor(ids);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println(
                "Yikes! Cannot create a processor from the data source.");
            return false;
        }

        p.addControllerListener(this);

        // Put the Processor into configured state so we can set
        // some processing options on the processor.
        p.configure();
        if (!waitForState(p, Processor.Configured))
        {
            System.err.println("Failed to configure the processor.");
            return false;
        }

        // Set the output content descriptor to QuickTime.
        p.setContentDescriptor(
            new ContentDescriptor(FileTypeDescriptor.MSVIDEO));

        // Query for the processor for supported formats.
        // Then set it on the processor.
        TrackControl tcs[] = p.getTrackControls();
        Format f[] = tcs[0].getSupportedFormats();
        if (f == null || f.length <= 0)
        {
            System.err.println(
                "The mux does not support the input format: "
                    + tcs[0].getFormat());
            return false;
        }

        tcs[0].setFormat(f[0]);

        System.err.println("Setting the track format to: " + f[0]);

        // We are done with programming the processor. Let's just
        // realize it.
        p.realize();
        if (!waitForState(p, Processor.Realized))
        {
            System.err.println("Failed to realize the processor.");
            return false;
        }

        // Now, we'll need to create a DataSink.
        DataSink dsink;
        if ((dsink = createDataSink(p, outML)) == null)
        {
            System.err.println(
                "Failed to create a DataSink for the given output MediaLocator: "
                    + outML);
            return false;
        }

        dsink.addDataSinkListener(this);
        fileDone = false;

        System.err.println("start processing...");

        // OK, we can now start the actual transcoding.
        try
        {
            p.start();
            dsink.start();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println("IO error during processing");
            return false;
        }

        // Wait for EndOfStream event.
        waitForFileDone();

        // Cleanup.
        try
        {
            dsink.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        p.removeControllerListener(this);

        System.err.println("...done processing.");

        return true;
    }

    /**
    * Create the DataSink.
    */
    private DataSink createDataSink(Processor p, MediaLocator outML)
    {

        DataSource ds;

        if ((ds = p.getDataOutput()) == null)
        {
            System.err.println(
                "Something is really wrong: the processor does not have an output DataSource");
            return null;
        }

        DataSink dsink;

        try
        {
            System.err.println("- create DataSink for: " + outML);
            dsink = Manager.createDataSink(ds, outML);
            dsink.open();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("Cannot create the DataSink: " + e);
            return null;
        }

        return dsink;
    }

    private Object waitSync = new Object();
    private boolean stateTransitionOK = true;

    /**
    * Block until the processor has transitioned to the given state.
    * Return false if the transition failed.
    */
    private boolean waitForState(Processor p, int state)
    {
        synchronized (waitSync)
        {
            try
            {
                while (p.getState() < state && stateTransitionOK)
                    waitSync.wait();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
        return stateTransitionOK;
    }

    /**
    * Controller Listener.
    */
    public void controllerUpdate(ControllerEvent evt)
    {

        if (evt instanceof ConfigureCompleteEvent
            || evt instanceof RealizeCompleteEvent
            || evt instanceof PrefetchCompleteEvent)
        {
            synchronized (waitSync)
            {
                stateTransitionOK = true;
                waitSync.notifyAll();
            }
        }
        else if (evt instanceof ResourceUnavailableEvent)
        {
            synchronized (waitSync)
            {
                stateTransitionOK = false;
                waitSync.notifyAll();
            }
        }
        else if (evt instanceof EndOfMediaEvent)
        {
            evt.getSourceController().stop();
            evt.getSourceController().close();
        }
    }

    private Object waitFileSync = new Object();
    private boolean fileDone = false;
    private boolean fileSuccess = true;

    /**
    * Block until file writing is done.
    */
    private boolean waitForFileDone()
    {
        synchronized (waitFileSync)
        {
            try
            {
                while (!fileDone)
                    waitFileSync.wait();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
        return fileSuccess;
    }

    /**
    * Event handler for the file writer.
    */
    public void dataSinkUpdate(DataSinkEvent evt)
    {

        if (evt instanceof EndOfStreamEvent)
        {
            synchronized (waitFileSync)
            {
                fileDone = true;
                waitFileSync.notifyAll();
            }
        }
        else if (evt instanceof DataSinkErrorEvent)
        {
            synchronized (waitFileSync)
            {
                fileDone = true;
                fileSuccess = false;
                waitFileSync.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
```

Everytime I tried to create a full HD video from full hd image, I always get stuck on function `waitForFileDone()`. Or if its successfully It takes a hours to make Full HD video. On normal video resolution, its work-well. Is there any other approach that more faster than wait end of stream  event?

Comment: You're explicitly blocking until the file is done processing...so I'm not sure what exactly you're looking for?  It doesn't seem apparent that you can continue forward *until* the file is complete, either.

Comment: @Makoto waitForFileDone blocking the process to complete. I'm looking any other approach instead of file complete. I've waiting several hours (almost 3 hours) to create Full HD video and this is insane! I'm running on Windows 10 X64 Machine with Intel i5 8200u series.

Comment: [Looks like an entry-level CPU](https://ark.intel.com/products/124967/Intel-Core-i5-8250U-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_40-GHz)...base clock speed below 2GHz and a very low TDP wattage output.  Not a ton of threads, either.  You're not going to be able to squeeze much more power out of that than you can.  3 hours is probably par for the course.  Do you have a beefier machine you can test this on?  You're very likely CPU and IO constrained for your machine and code optimizations will gain you no wins here.

Comment: @Makoto Yes, its categorized as entry-level CPU. Obviously, when I monitor Task Manager, It seems the CPU work-load percentage are very small between 1% and 10%. I believe this isn't  caused by the Java Program it self. When I check the memory usage which is SSD, its consume 1.6 Gigs. I believe the process are not continuing. Any idea?